# Flex grid with either 1 column or 2 columns

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have a design spec that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the container can either have a row of 2 columns or a row of 1 column. The row with 2 columns also has a space between.

Using flex, how can I make this possible? The columns comprise of simple hardcoded `<View>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `inine-flex` here if you don't want to use grid. Maybe this solution will help you:
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-od40tn?file=/index.html)